# How do I stop getting the "Google Maps API included multiple times on this page" error?

Tags: google-maps

I'm pretty new at Drupal 7.

I keep on getting this error **You have included the Google Maps API multiple times on this page. This may cause unexpected errors.**

I have a custom module which displays a map based on the address provided by the user into a form.

In order to get the map working properly, I had to add the following:

In the **.info** file

- scripts[] = google_map_api.js
- scripts[] = gmaps.js

In the **.module** file

```
function new_company_init() {   
  drupal_add_js('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true', 'external');
}
```

If I remove any of the 3 above statments, the map is not working.

I have been searching on the net but could not find any answer.
I do not want to use a module to manage the map.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! You are already using a module, so I don't see why not using a module that works instead of a module that doesn't work.

Comment: What module should fit better according the functionality described ? the map should be embeded into to the form.

Comment: We don't suggest modules/themes/distributions anymore.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not explain well. I am not using any mapping module like GMap or GetLocations or OpenLayers ,etc. I would like to avoid using any of these whenever possible.